# Compile ffmpeg into a shared library

Tags: android, makefile, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile ffmpeg into a single shared library for android.
The default compiling generates several static libs, such as libavutil.a, libavcodec.a and so on.

I want to compile those static libs into a single shared lib and write my Android.mk as follows:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    libavutil \
    libavcodec \
    libavformat \
    libswresample \
    libswscale \
    libavfilter \

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE := libffmpeg-shared
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But the output libffmpeg-shared.so has no symbols at all. How should modify the Android.mk?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have faced the same but in linux. If you dont want static but only shared,then search for equivalent version of options : `enable-shared`, `disable-static`

Comment: Have a look at : http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/ and consider my above options for `./configure` . But I dont think FFMPEG will give you single shared lib. For combining Sos : `gcc -shared -o x.so y.so z.so`

Comment: @Makesh I know with enable-shared, disable-static we get lib**.so libs. But whatever shared libs or static libs, I just want to make them to be one single lib-a single static lib or a single shared lib, thus we just need to load one library instead of 6. gcc command cannot be used in Android.mk. thanks all the same.